# How can I add a file extension after something from the database in MVC4 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently making a site in ASP/MVC4 razor. I want to add an image, depending from the database value.

I have this:

```
<img src="../images/@movie.Language.jpg" />
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="../images/@(movie.Language).jpg" />
```

You have to realize that Razor is parsing the '.jpg' as part of the expression, but since `Langauge` doesn't contain a `jpg` property/field, it throws an error.

By using the parentheses, you instruct Razor to only evaluate `movie.Language`, and not '.jpg'.

See [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax).